How to change the page if time has elapsed despite validation errors?
Currently, if a question has a validator or is required, the page will not change despite the time limit elapsing. The common scenario is that the user should be able to end a page faster but only if they do it correctly. Let's imagine a classroom test. All the questions in the test are required so a student will not skip a question by mistake. But if the time limit is reached, they shouldn't be able to complete the remaining questions. Now, the timer is stuck on 0:00 and the validators show errors.
My workaroud is to delete all validators and set isRequired to false when the time limit has been reached but I think I'm missing something here.
// for a single question
survey.onTimerTick.add((sender, options) => {
  if (
    survey.currentPage.name === "myPage" &&
    survey.currentPage.timeSpent >= survey.currentPage.maxTimeToFinish
  ) {
    const Q = survey.getQuestionByName("myQuestion");
    Q.clearErrors();
    Q.setPropertyValue("validators", []);
    Q.setPropertyValue("isRequired", false);
  }
});

I tried changing the page manually by setting the currentPage property but it results in the page changing twice.

You can set the
survey.validationAllowSwitchPages = true;

option

But that allows the user to switch pages despite validation errors as well. The users shouldn't be able to change the page if there are validation errors, but it should change when time elapses.

There is no such a built-in option is SurveyJS afaik. If you create a quiz with a timer per page and if you want user to be able to goto next page with some questions unanswered - what's the difference - whether user hasn't answered a question by a time limit or one doesn't want to give an answer? It looks like a rather weird case for me.

That would defeat the whole purpuse of validators. I want to validate the data to make sure that the user provides correct input. You are saying that if the user has a time limit, they should not be forced to provide correct input. E.g., I have a dynamic matrix that forces the user to complete at least 3 rows within 2 minutes. I don't want to let the user continue without the 3 answers but they cannot do it for longer than 2 minutes. It's not weird.
